# How to get a falloff from the edges of each face to the center?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I try to use Distribute Points on Surface with geometry nodes. Is there a way to control the density with a falloff from surrounding edges to each face center? Thanks!

Comment: should the density be higher inside the faces or on the edges?

Comment: I was needing center max, edges min but this is just a matter of modulating the gradient once obtained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version that measures the proximity of your mesh (subdivided to support interpolation,) to the edges of its un-subdivided self:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I get for not exploring, geo prox allows edges over transfer pos.

Comment: @Nathan Maybe... this time round, untypically. We can both rely on quellenform for the refinements, though :)

Answer (score 6):

And here is (for the sake of variety) another approach, which I don't want to claim is better or worse, but it produces just different results.

The advantage is the control over the point distribution, which is done by the node `Map Range`, and that the base mesh does not have to be divided (which could also be beneficial in some cases).

The disadvantage is that points are always created first, and then removed again (but this shouldn't be too tragic in most cases).

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Here are three faces from a cube with point density driven by distance to edge, interpolating to zero at the center of faces:

[image]

For us to interpolate to zero at the center of our faces, we need a vertex there, so we start by subdividing the mesh.  I then measure the distance to my original edges by measuring the distance to a wireframe object created by turning all original edges into curve objects and then back into mesh objects.  If my vertices are close to my original edges, within a precision fudge factor, they get density of 1; if they are far, which will only happen at the centers of the faces of my original geometry, they will get a density of 0.  The points distribution will take this into account, interpolating linearly from original edges to original face centers.

If we want to control the density gradient precisely, we can, but we need additional vertices to control that gradient:

[image]

We capture our density attribute, then subdivide the mesh.  By capturing the attribute we make it so that the subdivision generates interpolated values for our density from our previous vertices.  We can then run these values through any curve we'd like.

Comment: Thanks! At least  I know it's possible. Can you please show how this would work with the new nodes that replaced the convenient Transfer Attribute node in 3.4 ?

Comment: @bestelix I don't know; I don't download alphas (or betas.)